# Enabling PDO in php.ini file resulted in 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: php, windows, pdo, internal-server-error

When I enabled PDO in php.ini file in root directory (C:\PHP) on Windows Server 2008 Standard it resulted in 500 Internal Server Error.

I use IIS as web server and MSSQL as database.

3 Websites are hosted on the server.  2 websites are running fine when PDO is enabled. Only 1 goes down with error message 500 Internal Server Error.

Please help. How do I fix this?

Below are the codes I uncommented from the php.ini file.

```
[PHP_PDO]
extension=php_pdo.dll

[PHP_PDO_MSSQL]
extension=php_pdo_mssql.dll

[PHP_PDO_ODBC]
extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll
```

Thanks.

Comment: maybe you can take a look in the error log?

Comment: Here are the application logs from the server:                                    Faulting application php-cgi.exe, version 5.2.3.3, time stamp 0x465ecf91, faulting module php-cgi.exe, version 5.2.3.3, time stamp 0x465ecf91, exception code 0xc0000005, fault offset 0x0000167a, process id 0xc10, application start time 0x01d055b9911f9a24.

Comment: sorry meant the php error log

Comment: Issue has been resolved. No need to uncomment above extensions under Local Variables in the php.ini file.